# onSingleClicked Broken/Stopped Working - Excel Office-JS Add-In

Tags: excel, office-js

I generated a function to work w/ `onSingleClicked` and recently I noticed it wasn't working after it had been in production and working for some time.

Note: I am on Windows using Desktop version currently.

I don't think I changed any related code, but to post this Q, I trimmed down to the basics and it still didn't work. My guess is something broke it in the Excel API?

Can anyone confirm if they are able to get it to work? A working example I can build off?

Here is the docs --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetsingleclickedeventargs?view=excel-js-preview

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
ws.onSingleClicked.add((event) => {
    return Excel.run((context) => {
        console.log(`Click detected at ${event.address} (pixel offset from upper-left cell corner: ${event.offsetX}, ${event.offsetY})`);
        return context.sync();
    });
});

console.log("The worksheet click handler is registered.");
```

Updates:

I ran my Add-In on office.com and I was able to use my click events (when zoom = 100%, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3597).

But, I can't get anything on desktop.

I am running `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.21008) 64-bit`

Comment: Is this the same question also posted at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3597 ? If so we're researching that issue and should update this question once we have a resolution. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidChesnut I was able to upload my code to `office.com` on a new workbook by sideloading my add-in. I can confirm that I was able to repro the "Zoom" issue, but my click events did work. When I use desktop, my click events don't work at all. Probably related! I'll post on that git link as well

Comment: @DavidChesnut can you get it to work on desktop at all?

Comment: It works for me on Excel on Windows. I assume you surrounded the code above in `await Excel.run(async (context) => {...` ? Which version of Excel are you running?

Comment: @DavidChesnut yes its wrapped in a context call. I'm running `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.21008) 64-bit`. Is there a github example I could try loading? Are you on `x32` or `x64`?

Comment: It works again now... Basically nothing changed on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And... it just started working again!

I figured it out I think. Its broken still when the browser uses IE as the backend vs Edge. Another discrepancy between IE and Edge...